# Undefined method with rails runner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, whenever, runner

I'm using the gem [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) and I can't get my runner instruction working.

I'm getting this error:

```
/Users/bl0b/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:53:in `eval': undefined method `run' for #<Class:0x007f97d88744a8> (NoMethodError)
    from (eval):1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/bl0b/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:53:in `eval'
    from /Users/bl0b/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:53:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/bl0b/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `require'
    from /Users/bl0b/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I have the following code in my `shedule.rb` :

```
set :environment, 'development' 

     every 1.minutes do
       runner "Crawler.run", :output => '/Users/bl0b/Projects/crawler/cron.log'  
     end
```

and in my `app/models/crawler.rb` I have the following code:

```
class Crawler < ActiveRecord::Base

  def run
    puts "toto"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are attempting to call a class method on `Crawler`, but the method is defined as an instance method. To make your method a class method you can define it like so:

```
def self.run
  puts "toto"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like , If you don't need to make the method as a self method of the Class.

```
 every 1.minutes do
   runner "Crawler.new.run", :output => '/Users/bl0b/Projects/crawler/cron.log'  
 end
```